# Node-Red dashboard: is it possible to send and get a response of a html GET request within a template node?

Tags: angularjs, node-red

I can't display the value of variable `Location` as a result of an HTML GET request using the following code. Can someone please help ?

```
<script>
(function() {
(function(scope, html) {
    scope.getLocation() {
        http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/1').then(function() { 
        scope.Location = data.albumId;
        });
    };
})(scope, html);
})();
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this in the template and not as part of the Node-RED flow?

Comment: The idea is to avoid having to handle messages coming in and out... I have noticed that messages cause some undesired behaviour in some AngularJS elements, for example to erase selected values of a radio button.

Comment: Your `.then(...)` function has no args -- perhaps `.then(function(data) {...})` would actually let you get at the data returned from the http.get()?

Comment: adding args to the function unfortunately did not work... should I have used `$http.get` instead? It did not work either...